# Filament php Toggle

Tags: laravel, boolean, toggle, laravel-filament

How I can use toogle for insert data( 0 1) to database?
I couldn't find this question's answer from Google in two days.

`Toggle::make('is_active')`

I write code as above but it doesn't work. It works as button but not change data on database.

Comment: You'll want to post a lot more info to get proper help.  Some questions to answer offhand:
- are you able to save any data to the database?
- show the code you're using to post the request to the backend
- show the code you're using to accept the request on the backend and write to the database

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. Just need to add `'is_active'` to `$fillable` in Model:

```
    protected $fillable = [
  
      'is_active',

];
```